# Probability of point selected on a line

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

A point is selected at random on a line segment of length $l$.

What is the probability that none of the two segments is smaller than $\frac{l}{3}$?

Progress:
Let $X$ = length of the segments

$X$~ U[$0,l$]

$f_X(x)$ = $\frac{1}{x}$ $0 \leq x \leq l$

And we need P($\frac{l}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{2l}{3}$). How do I find this probability?

Comment: Hint: Do you know how to find P(a<x<b) based on the given PDF of x?

Comment: Is the answer $\frac{1}{3}$? @NimaS

Comment: And Your PDF is not $\frac{1}{x}$. I assume that's just the typo. You are correct in saying that x is from a uniform distribution. Therefore your $f_{X}(x)$ is....

Comment: is it 1/$l$ instead? @NimaS

Comment: Yes. You are correct.